Combinatorics question
Let me preface this by saying that this might be a trivial question for some of you.
I want to find a formula that will help me automatically calculate the number of occurrences of certain kind of combinations. It's a bit confusing, so let me give an example:
Suppose we have 4 raters that rate entities in 3 distinct categories ("A", "B" and "C").
I'd like to know the formula for the number of each kind of combination:

All raters rate the entity in a single category (for instance, three A's)
Two of three raters rate an entity in one category, and another rate's it in a different category (two A's and one B or C)
Each rater choosing a different category (one A, one B and one C)

I've read some books on combinatorics, but can't seem to find an answer that works for every case (3 raters 3 categories, 3 raters 2 categories, 4 raters 2 categories, etc.)
Can any of you please help?

Expand the polynomial $(A+B+C)^4$ and inspect the coefficients.
